# Transparent panel render in wrong order

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

I have a panel which has a transparent background. When I add a few of these to a control, the child with the highest index is rendered on top. Can someone tell me what's going on and how I can solve this?

This is the code of the panel:

```
public ref class TransparentPanel : public Panel
{
public:
    Bitmap^ _image;

    TransparentPanel(Bitmap^ image){_image = image;Width = image->Width;Height = image->Height;}

    virtual property System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^ CreateParams{
        System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^ get(void) override {
            System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^ cp = Panel::CreateParams;
            cp->ExStyle |= 0x00000020;//WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return cp;
        }
    }

    virtual void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs^ e) override {}
    virtual void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs^ e) override {e->Graphics->DrawImage(_image, Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height));}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you expect but it's common practices to draw the last inserted control on top of the previous ones.

If you have a precise ordering you can play with z-indexing so that your panels will be positioned correctly.

Otherwise can't you simply insert them in reverse order ;) that should fix the issue.

Comment: This page states that the child with the `0` index will appear on top. I'm trying to fix an annoying bug, but I have no idea where it goes wrong. This is the only lead I have at the moment. `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx`

Comment: And using the z-index does not change anything? e.g. for the ith control you could set a z-index of i so it will appear under the previous one as you'd like.

Comment: Never mind, I found more problems related to rendering, like when I resize the window, controls are only partially rendered and some objects are switched. I'm going to ask a similar question as soon as I know exactly what's going on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is over a year old but I've been struggling with a similar issue for a couple of days now. As I have now found a solution that seems to work I thought I'd post here for future sufferers (myself included!).

It seems that setting the **WS_EX_TRANSPARENT** style (0x20) for a series of custom painted controls that sit on top of each other has the strange effect that they are painted in an order opposite to their z-order, i.e. the control with z-index of 0 will be painted first (to test this, write each control's z-index to the Console in your overridden OnPaint methods).

The solution that seems to work for me so far is to extend the parent control (in my case a DevExpress PanelControl, though I have also tried this with a standard .Net Panel too) and enable the **WS_EX_COMPOSITED** extended window style there:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;   //WS_EX_COMPOSITED

        return cp;
    }
}
```

This style setting simply reverses the order in which child controls are painted (so it becomes bottom to top), thus solving the problem :)

For more information on extended window styles see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx.
This page warns that there will be flashing using this in Windows 8 but I have tried in Windows 8.1 and didn't see any problems so maybe it has been fixed.

I can only assume that .NET controls are somehow rendered differently (possibly using clipping regions etc), which is why they don't exhibit the same behaviour, but painting controls in top to bottom order does seem like a bug to me as I can't think of a situation where you would want to do that!

Comment: For my project I needed transparency which WinForms does not really support. I started using WPF, it works great. It has transparency and is faster.